# How to run a game in the cloud and capture the video in an automated way

Tags: video, cloud, gpu, game-development

I am looking for some expert hints on how to achieve the following in an automated manner:

- Install a game in the cloud, preferably virtualised to reduce the costs.
- Upload a replay file of a game and have it run inside the game, which requires in-game rendering, and at the same time record video
- Convert the video to a compressed format (e.g. AVI)

Preferred infrastructure would be Windows. Any hints as to Cloud providers with GPU (except AWS), how to automate the starting of the game and in-game clicks to play the replay and video-capturing tools are very welcome.

Comment: why not just use twitch?